# Add A,B,C letters to Duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need big help from you I am using sql server 2008 and I want to get the output using sql query.

I have a following data in the table.

```
Id      Code
-----------------
1       01012
2       01012
3       01012
4       01012
5       01013
6       01013
7       01014
```

I need Following output

```
Id      Code
-----------------
1       01012
2       01012A
3       01012B
4       01012C
5       01013
6       01013A
7       01014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQL Server 2012+ Solution**

*Can be adpated to 2008 be replacing `CONCAT` with `+` and `CHOOSE` with `CASE`.*

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(ID INT, Code VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
SELECT 1, '01012'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, '01012'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, '01012'
UNION ALL SELECT 4, '01012'
UNION ALL SELECT 5, '01013'
UNION ALL SELECT 6, '01013'
UNION ALL SELECT 7, '01014';
```

Query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ID, Code,
    [rn] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY id)
  FROM #tab
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Code = CONCAT(Code, CHOOSE(rn, '', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')) -- next letters
FROM cte;
```

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372339)**

Comment: Thank you very much.It is a big help

Comment: This is limit to duplicate till F, Felix query is better option.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`. When Rn = 1, retain the original `Code` else, add `A`, `B`, and so on.

To determine which letter to add, the formula is `CHAR(65 - RN - 2)`.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Id)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Code =  CASE
                WHEN Rn = 1 THEN Code
                ELSE Code + CHAR(65 + Rn - 2)
            END
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    case 
        when rownum > 1 then code + char(65+rownum-2)
        else code  
    end as code,
    id 
from (
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() over( partition by code order by code) as rownum
    from #tab
)c
```